# char array members in struct - value copied to both members

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

When copying strings to struct and printing only one attribute, both members of struct are printed. Why does this happen and how to overcome this ?

```
typedef struct  {

  char a1[14];
  char a2[2];  

} X;


void main() {

  X x;

  strcpy(x.a1, "55555555555555");
  printf("A1 - %s\n\n", x.a1); 

  strcpy(x.a2, "D5");
  printf("A1 - %s\n\n", x.a1);
  printf("A2 - %s\n\n", x.a2); 

}
```

Output:

```
A1 - 55555555555555

A1 - 55555555555555D5

A2 - D5
```

Why did D5 append to A1 here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is too small, you need `N` characters +1 for a string of `N` characters.

It is strictly *undefined behavior*, but the observed behavior could be attributed to the fact that the storage for the `struct` is allocated contiguously thus you are printing a "*big string*" composed by the two arrays.

But that assumption is also wrong, because the "*big string*" lacks a `'\0'` terminator since you have used all the possible elements in the array and copied non `'\0'` characters into them.

So the actual result of your program should be considered unpredictable, and what you observe as a behavior is in fact, **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Ok, tried it and works now.. So, struct allocates memory for all its members serially ? and since there was no null, output was appended when A1 was read ? Am i right ?

Comment: @user691197 Not entirely. I've updated the answer explaining why that was the output. But it's strictly inexplicable, because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/89920-structs-sequential-memory.html might be helpful @user691197

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** A string is not just a character array but instead **a character array terminated by `nul` character** (`\0`)

Here you have:

```
char a1[14];
char a2[2];
```

and you initialize them to

```
5555... 14 times
D5
```

**here you don't have `\0` character to mark the end of string at the end** and so when you try to print the character array it results in **undefined behavior**.

try giving a space at the end for `\0` character in each character array

```
char a1[15]; //extra space for the null terminating character
char a2[3];  //similarly here
```